# Skipping tokens in yacc

Tags: token, yacc, skip

I want to have a grammar rule like below in my yacc file:

```
insert_statement: INSERT INTO NAME (any_token)* ';'
```

We can skip all the tokens until a given token at an error, in yacc as follows:

```
stat: error ';'
```

Is there any mechanism to skip any number of characters in yacc, when there is no error?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a scanner before your parser to generate the tokens? You could skip characters in there.

Comment: Yes, I am using lex. But what I want to do is to identify some stream of tokens, then skip some tokens (not characters) until a given token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After sometime I could solve my problem the following way and would like to mention it as it would be helpful to someone:

- Add a token definition to lex including the characters that should be in a skipping token:

  **<*>[A-Za-z0-9_:.-]* { return SKIPPINGTOKS; }**

  (this would identify any token like a, 1, hello, hello123 etc.)
- Then add the following such rules to yacc as required:

  **insert_statement: INSERT INTO NAME skipping_portion ';'**

  **skipping_portion: SKIPPINGTOKS | skipping_portion SKIPPINGTOKS**

Hope this may help someone...

Answer (score 2):

I think you would want to do something like this.  It skips any and all tokens that are not the semicolon.

```
insert_statement: INSERT INTO NAME discardable_tokens_or_epsilon ';' ;

discardable_tokens_or_epsilon:    discardable_tokens
                                | epsilon
                                ;

discardable_tokens:   discardable_tokens  discardable_token
                    | discardable_token
                    ;

discardable_token:   FOO 
                   | BAR
                   | BLETCH
                   ...et cetera... anything other than a semicolon
                   ; 

epsilon: ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't specify a production rule containing those tokens, you'd like to skip.